# Are there alternatives to Parse.com for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, parse-platform

I currently use parse.com to manage users. They have a great API, decent backend for me to manage stuff. But I'd prefer to host my own data.

The server backend, I could whip that up in php very easily. But I'm struggling to find a decent library/framework on the iOS side of things to replicate what Parse's framework does.

To do things like easy login/logout, having a user 'cached' with a saved file, easy to use methods for using blocks to send data in the background. Any clues as to where to look or what to search for to find a similar open source library that I can integrate with my own systems?

Comment: I have updated my post +(Own backend server and communications)

Comment: see http://deployd.com and http://helios.io