# Can I use Parse without Facebook integration?

Tags: ios, cloud, parse-platform

In other words: Are there better alternatives to Parse if you want to develop a cloud-enabled app and don't need any Facebook integration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there alternatives to Parse.com for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811434/are-there-alternatives-to-parse-com-for-ios)

Comment: It depends on what your wanting to do, if you looking for something exactly like Parse but without Facebook, there isn't anything....but...You don't have to use the Facebook component to use Parse? Is there something else you don't like about it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to integrate Facebook into your app, if you're using Parse. It's only an option. But if you're using CocoaPods you can get errors if you do not attach the Facebook SDK to your project.